# MongoDB sub Documents fetch as different documents with document count using NestJs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have MongoDb Document like this,
So I need to write a query => {"enrolments.date" : { $gte:"2020-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"} }, but i need that documents as separate documents, in this example, document count two, so how can i do?

```
    "_id" : "10000",
    "Class" : "A",
    "enrolments" : [ 
        {"id" : "10000-1","name" : "Test1","month":"2020-11","date":"2020-12-08T10:37:00.000Z"},
        {"id" : "10000-2","name" : "Test2","month":"2020-12","date":"2020-12-07T10:37:00.000Z"},
        {"id" : "10000-3","name" : "Test3","month":"2020-12","date":"2020-11-16T10:37:00.000Z"}
    ]
}
```

`Output =>`

```
    "_id":"10000",
    "Class":"A",
    "enrolments":[ 
        {"id":"10000-1","name":"Test1","month":"2020-11","date":"2020-12-08T10:37:00.000Z"}
    ]
},{
    "_id" : "10000",
    "Class" : "A",
    "enrolments" : [
        {"id" : "10000-2","name" : "Test2","month":"2020-12","date":"2020-12-07T10:37:00.000Z"}
    ]
}
```

`like this`

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `$unwind`. So you should write something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ 
{ 
     $unwind : "$enrolments" 
},
{
     $match : { "$enrolments.date" : { $gte:"2020-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"} }
} 
] )
```